# Isekai manga where the protagonist is repeatedly reincarnated during the first chapter

Tags: story-identification, manga, isekai

The story for the first chapter goes as follows:

MC is summoned by a goddess in white who gives him a special ability and sends him to a new world. After mere seconds he is summoned back at the white room where the goddess was. This repeats several times, until finally the goddess makes it so that this time he stays in that world.

Comment: ShiroNeko69, when you return, if you think this is the correct answer, you can accept it by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons as per the [tour].

Answer (score 3):

As per the answer to [Isekai manga where the main character gets summoned multiple times to another world](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/236005/isekai-manga-where-the-main-character-gets-summoned-multiple-times-to-another-wo/236009#236009), this may be *[I Was Summoned to a Parallel Fantasy World for Too Many Times](https://www.novelupdates.com/series/i-was-summoned-to-a-parallel-fantasy-world-for-too-many-times/)* (original title *Meccha Shoukan Sareta Ken* or *めっちゃ召喚された件　～世界法則無視のチート権化～*)

[image: Front over of Meccha Shoukan Sareta Ken]

> A boy’s whole class gets summoned to another world, except he’s the only who one was transferred to a different one. Just when he gets used to his new life, he gets summoned to another world again, and again.

Comment: The question/answer pairing reads like a joke :P