# Isekai manga where the main character gets summoned multiple times to another world

Tags: story-identification, manga, isekai

I'm looking for an *isekai* manga where the main character gets summoned from one world to the next rapidly, acquiring more power each time. He gets summoned as a hero, a demon lord, a vampire, and one time some magic eye researcher tries to take his eyes. There was a summoning room where a goddess gave him a power each time. Each time he was summoned it would be mere minutes before he was summoned to another world again leaving no time to do anything.

Comment: Ah, can't mark it as a Duplicate unless accepted, but I copied the essentials of my answer over.

Comment: And thank you for the accept, Sample386. :) Didn't even have to point you to the [tour]. I hope you stick around. We're a fun community.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*[I Was Summoned to a Parallel Fantasy World for Too Many Times](https://www.novelupdates.com/series/i-was-summoned-to-a-parallel-fantasy-world-for-too-many-times/)* (original title *Meccha Shoukan Sareta Ken* or *めっちゃ召喚された件　～世界法則無視のチート権化～*)

[image: Front cover of Meccha Shoukan Sareta Ken]

> A boy’s whole class gets summoned to another world, except he’s the only who one was transferred to a different one. Just when he gets used to his new life, he gets summoned to another world again, and again.

I poked around and found a scan of it and indeed, one of his early misadventures involves the magic eye researcher going after his eyes.

[image: Magic eye researcher explaining his plan to harvest magic eyes]

Found by searching for `isekai manga summoned repeatedly`, which brought me to [this listing](https://www.novelupdates.com/stag/summoned-hero/) with Google having shown an excerpt mentioning the promising title of *I Was Summoned to a Parallel Fantasy World for Too Many Times* which I then followed up on.