# Fantasy/isekai manga where the human main character is summoned multiple times for 60 seconds each

Tags: story-identification, manga, isekai

It's about a certain main character who is a human and gets summoned in another world but after 60 seconds he's suddenly in front of goddess-sama again and he gets summoned again by the demons and like his first summons he is suddenly in front of goddess-sama again. In his 3rd summons he is being experimented and he came back in front of goddess-sama and in his 4th summons he met a dying girl who has wishes but he said he wouldn't last longer than a minute so the girl is devastated. So in his 5th summons he became a demon lord, after he came back in front of goddess-sama, she said that she found the problem and fixed it so in his 6th summons is a complete (so every time he gets summoned he acquired a certain power/blessings).

Comment: Likely a dupe of [Isekai manga where the main character gets summoned multiple times to another world](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/236005/isekai-manga-where-the-main-character-gets-summoned-multiple-times-to-another-wo)

Comment: @Shaina-kun: When you return, you can accept a correct answer by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons as per the [tour].

Answer (score 1):

As per Valorum's comment, I believe this is *[I Was Summoned to a Parallel Fantasy World for Too Many Times](https://www.novelupdates.com/series/i-was-summoned-to-a-parallel-fantasy-world-for-too-many-times/)* (original title *Meccha Shoukan Sareta Ken* or *めっちゃ召喚された件　～世界法則無視のチート権化～*)

[image: Front cover of Meccha Shoukan Sareta Ken]

> A boy’s whole class gets summoned to another world, except he’s the only [one who] was transferred to a different one. Just when he gets used to his new life, he gets summoned to another world again, and again.

I poked around and found a scan of it and indeed, one of his early misadventures involves the magic eye researcher going after his eyes for an experiment. In a later chapter, he encounters a magic-user who has sacrificed her life force to grant the necessary power to the summoned hero, only to learn he's being summoned back (he rather callously lets her know that her sacrifice was futile, mainly because he's become jaded at this point).

[image: Magic eye researcher explaining his plan to harvest magic eyes]

Found by searching for `isekai manga summoned repeatedly`, which brought me to [this listing](https://www.novelupdates.com/stag/summoned-hero/) with Google having shown an excerpt mentioning the promising title of *I Was Summoned to a Parallel Fantasy World for Too Many Times* which I then followed up on.

Answer copied over from where I provided it [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/236005/isekai-manga-where-the-main-character-gets-summoned-multiple-times-to-another-wo/236009#236009).