# MC gets summoned multiple times and has to escape

Tags: story-identification, magic, manga, isekai, reincarnation

I'm looking for a manga where MC gets summoned around 4 or 3 times but after his last summon, he is in a room with multiple people and has to escape the room that is somewhat of a playground, like a park with equipment for young schoolchildren to play on. He can take people's skills and he's also a vampire.

No, it's not Meccha Shoukan Sareta Ken but it was similar to that.

Can someone please find it for me?
I read it a year ago looking for other Isekai manga to read but never got the name.

Comment: Could you elaborate on the "escape the room" part? And is this a summoning manga or a reincarnation manga - i.e. does he die multiple times? A more specific question; does the protagonist die alongside many classmates, they all get reincarnated, he dies again, gets experimented on, escapes but is promptly killed by his former classmates, and reincarnates again? Does that sound familiar?

Comment: Curious, can you point out some of the ways this differs from *Meccha Shoukan Sareta Ken*? I respect that you're certain it's not the right answer, but it does match on pretty much all of the listed points, including being a vampire and being able to steal skills.

Comment: well to begine with mc is in a white room with other people and are told they have to escape the room after a while they all agree to escape but sooner or later they learn that they have skills while mc learns he is a vampire who can steal skills while trying to escape with the female elf friend that he just made of course the people he was with where other races

Comment: The story I was thinking of was "Yondome wa Iyana Shi Zokusei Majutsushi". I'm pretty sure this isn't it, but could you explicitly rule it out? Additionally, how old is the protagonist? Does he keep his human form in this room, or is he more like a floating soul (e.g. Isekai Teni, Jirai Tsuki.)? Is the white room an actual room, or a white void, or possibly a savannah (e.g. Saikyou no Shokugyou wa Yuusha Demo Kenja Demo Naku Kanteishi (Kari) Rashii Desu yo?)? None of those are good matches but they at least have some stuff in common.

Comment: Playground, like a park with equipment for young schoolchildren to play on? If not, what do you mean by playground?

Comment: yes it was like that but it was in a white room

Answer (score 1):

I suspect this is *[I Was Summoned to a Parallel Fantasy World for Too Many Times](https://www.novelupdates.com/series/i-was-summoned-to-a-parallel-fantasy-world-for-too-many-times/)* (original title *Meccha Shoukan Sareta Ken* or *めっちゃ召喚された件　～世界法則無視のチート権化～*) as per [Isekai manga where the main character gets summoned multiple times to another world](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/236005/) (cannibalizing my own answer):

[image: Front cover of Meccha Shoukan Sareta Ken]

> A boy’s whole class gets summoned to another world, except he’s the only who one was transferred to a different one. Just when he gets used to his new life, he gets summoned to another world again, and again.

I know that he became a vampire, and could steal skills, and that, after multiple summons and gifts (and a growing relationship with the goddess he keeps getting called back to), he is summoned among a bunch of others and does his best to get out of it, as he's not exactly the heroic type. Other vivid details include a magic eye researcher who plans to remove his eye to steal his gift, a princess who offers her virtue to him in exchange for him saving the kingdom (which he doesn't have a chance to capitalize on before he's summoned back), and a black magic researcher (also a young female) who used the last of her life force to summon him to pass on her magical knowledge.

[image: Magic eye researcher explaining his plan to harvest magic eyes]

Although you've confirmed this isn't the one, a page with him discussing how he still has the Skill Theft power, although it's now filtered through his vampirism:

[image: Image with him describing the Skill Theft change]

Comment: sorry bro but it's not this one although it was something like this but i hope you find what your looking for