# Main character has a strong soul which made him be sent to a bunch of worlds

Tags: story-identification, manga

Main character is reincarnated but seconds after he is sent to another world, and this happens like 7 times, each time gaining an ability related to that world.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  This seems more like the pitch for a story than the story itself.  What are the worlds?  What are the powers?  Why does he stop getting transferred to other worlds, and what happens when he does?

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. Was this in full colour or mostly black & white? Also, can you tell us anything about the worlds the main character was sent to, or the situations he found himself in?

Comment: If anyone correctly identifies this, you can mark their answer as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) by clicking on the check mark beneath the voting buttons, as per the [tour].

Comment: Accepted thank you to those who helped

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may be thinking of ***[Summoned to a Parallel Fantasy World Many Times](https://www.mangaupdates.com/series/nql6707/meccha-shoukan-sareta-ken-the-comic)***.

From Baka-Updates:

> Name’s Inori Takafuji. I’m not really much of a “go-getter,” if you catch my drift—sleep’s more my style—but getting summoned to another world kinda messed things up. Bit hard to chill when you’ve got a king in your face telling you there’s a bad guy you’ve gotta go slay or whatever, you know? Plot twist, though—it’s actually not so bad. Getting the hero treatment sounds pretty nice, right? But then it happens again! Some other clown summons me, I get my obligatory superpower, and off I go. And sure, that’s fine. It happens, sometimes you get isekai’d to the wrong place. But then it happens AGAIN! Someone ELSE summons me, I get ANOTHER superpower, and then I’m somewhere totally new. Repeat ad nauseam. No idea what’s going on, but all I want is one thing: stop !@#$ing summoning me!

The protagonist, Takafuji Inori, is granted a skill by a goddess and sent to another world, but to the surprise of both of them, he finds himself back in front of the goddess ten minutes later. She decides to send him to a different world, but says she has to grant him another skill first, as those are the rules. This keeps happening, and Inori soon has over half a dozen skills listed on his status screen. He asks the goddess why this keeps happening, and she indicates that it has something to do with him having an unusually powerful soul.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is it just me, or have isekai manga gone too far? Now they have gotten so stereotyped that they have gone meta: "sometimes you get isekai'd to the wrong place," "got my obligatory superpower."

Comment: Thanks to both of you you got it correct

Answer (score 3):

It's not a 100% match, because he's summoned, not reincarnated, and it's actually ambiguous as to why he happens to get summoned so many times, but perhaps *[I Was Summoned to a Parallel Fantasy World for Too Many Times](https://www.novelupdates.com/series/i-was-summoned-to-a-parallel-fantasy-world-for-too-many-times/)* (original title *Meccha Shoukan Sareta Ken* or *めっちゃ召喚された件　～世界法則無視のチート権化～*) as per [Isekai manga where the main character gets summoned multiple times to another world](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/236005/isekai-manga-where-the-main-character-gets-summoned-multiple-times-to-another-wo)?

[image: Front cover of Meccha Shoukan Sareta Ken]

> A boy’s whole class gets summoned to another world, except he’s the only who one was transferred to a different one. Just when he gets used to his new life, he gets summoned to another world again, and again.